# Blackberry API to change the home screen background image

Tags: blackberry, background, homescreen

I am trying to develop a Blackberry app that will change the Home Screen background image(not the application background image) periodically (just like WallPaper changer for windows) based on configurable time parameter.

Is it possible to change the HomeScreen background programatically. is there any API to do that..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A BlackBerry device application can use net.rim.blackberry.api.homescreen.HomeScreen.setBackgroundImage(String uri) (Since:
    JDE 4.7.0) with an image file that resides in flash memory or a microSD Card to set the background image. A typical format for the URI is "file:///store/home/user/pictures/file.jpg." Invoking net.rim.blackberry.api.homescreen.HomeScreen.setBackgroundImage(String uri) will override images that other applications have set.